# How are these priors generated?

Tags: self-study, bayesian, prior

I am trying going through an exercise, I don't understand how the information provided in the text below transitions into the parameters displayed in the beta priors. How are these informative priors generated?

This is the model:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please include the parts below that line in the screenshot?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy done, thank you.

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a photograph or screenshot (see 
[here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). When you retype the question,
add the [tag:self-study] tag & read 
[its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. 
We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks, I would have typed the question however am not well versed in writing equations in Latex.

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expert starts 90% shure that the expected survival time in absence of the contaminant is less then 40 and 90% shure that it is greater then 10.

This is the information on which we base the prior to $\beta_0$ because the absence of the contaminent means we have a $conc_i = 0$ and thus $\beta_1$ does not matter. We look for a normal distribution with 10% of the mass below log(10) and 10% of the mass above log(40). As the normal distribution is symmetric around the mean, the mean of that standard deviation will be in the middle between log(10) and log(40), so `(log(10) + log(40))/2 = 2.9957`. (Your screenshot says the mean was `3`).

Now all we need is a standard deviation with `qnorm(c(.1, .9), mean = 2.9957, sd = x) == c(log(10), log(40)) == c(2.302585, 3.688879)`.

Now there will be a number of ways to come to a standard deviation. For example a graphical approach:

```
curve(qnorm(.1, mean = 3, sd = x), ylim = c(1.5, 4.5),
      ylab = expression(log(lambda)), xlab = expression(sigma),col = "blue")
curve(qnorm(.9, mean = 3, sd = x), add = TRUE, col = "blue")
abline(h= c(log(10), log(40)), lty = 3, col = "grey")
abline(v = .54, lty = 2, col = "grey")
```

[image]

Let's try the `.54` from your book:

```
> qnorm(c(.1, .9), mean = 2.9957, sd = .54)
[1] 2.303662 3.687738
```

Close enough. I will leave the $\beta_1$ for you to try because after all this is a self-study question, even if it does not have a self-study tag.